# One test case is showing time limit exceeded.Why?

Tags: python

Question- Given an m x n matrix of 0s and 1s, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in place.

```
def value(arr):
    lk=[]
    ll=[]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if(arr[i][j]==0):
                lk.append(i)
                ll.append(j)

    for ele in lk:
        for j in range(n):
              arr[ele][j]=0
    for ele in ll:
        for i in range(m):
            arr[i][ele]=0

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            print(arr[i][j],end=' ')
        print()


str=input().split()
m,n=int(str[0]),int(str[1])
arr = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]

value(arr)
```

Comment: I think this question belongs in https://cs.stackexchange.com/ as it is not about your code not working, but rather that it is not fast enough to solve your problem

Comment: Maybe use a `set` datatype for `lk`and `ll` instead to automatically eliminate duplicates. Currently, if 20 numbers on the same row are zero, you clear out the same row 20 times, once for each zero.

Comment: As for a reason why your solution doesn't work, your program currently runs at a worse case O(m^2n^2) time complexity, where (m,n) are the dimensions of the matrix. The suggestion that @JoachimIsaksson makes above would reduce the complexity to O(mn).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not explained very well since you haven't told what is the test case is. But it's okay since you are new to StackOverflow.

After some googling, I found this was a question in leetcode. The first thing, the code works but it is very slow. In competitive programming like leetcode, you should write a very optimized code which can solve the problem in the least amount of time.

```
    def setZeroes(matrix):

        R = len(matrix)
        C = len(matrix[0])
        rows, cols = set(), set()

        # Essentially, we mark the rows and columns that are to be made zero
        for i in range(R):
            for j in range(C):
                if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                    rows.add(i)
                    cols.add(j)

        # Iterate over the array once again and using the rows and cols sets, update the elements
        for i in range(R):
            for j in range(C):
                if i in rows or j in cols:
                    matrix[i][j] = 0
```

As you can see this both your and proposed answer has nested loops. But the proposed answer has only two loops while your answer has 4 loops.

I hope you can understand why your code works but inefficient.

Comment: Sir, this approach I already tried but this makes every element of array '0'.

Comment: Hey, don't call me sir :). It works fine, please copy and place the code in leetcode it should work, I just checked. Let me know if an error occurs